# ArcGIS SelectLayerByLocation_managerment Error 000368: Invalid Input Data

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

Good afternoon,

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to get arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_managerment to work and cannot find a solution - I am using ArcMap/Catalog 10.2  .

I have a large polyline dataset that I am trying to split up by several separate polygon layer files. The idea is that the script will cycle through the layer files, select the polyline parts that sit within X meters and export them to a separate folder. Here is my code:

```
arcpy.AddMessage("\n Checking Script for Errors...")
                        #Script to split one layer (OSMM/OSVML) into parts, parts defined by another layer.
import arcpy
import os
            #References users Map document - get parameter input from prompt
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Frame")[0]
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

        #For loop to iterate through all layers in dataframe
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df):
                    #Get layer name
            layerName = lyr.name
                    #Skip the OS File
            if layerName == "OSMM_Line_Detail":
                    arcpy.AddMessage("\n Skipping " + layerName)
            else:
                            #Inform users of layer being processed
                    arcpy.AddMessage("\n Processing: " + layerName)
                            #Select the wanted layer that is within a distance of the current layer
                    arcpy.AddMessage("\n Select by location")
                    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('OSMM_Line_Detail',"WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",layerName,arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3),"NEW_SELECTION")                        
                            #Create directory for file (http://desk.stinkpot.org:8080/tricks/index.php/2006/07/create-a-directory-in-python/)
                    dirname = ("C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Test Data\Basemapping and Boundary Data\Split line by area\Line " + layerName)
                    if not os.path.isdir(dirname + "/"):
                            arcpy.AddMessage("\n Directory not found, creating directoy for: " + layerName)
                            os.mkdir(dirname + "/")
                            #Exports the selection of layer to new directory
                    arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2), ""C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\Test Data\Basemapping and Boundary Data\Split line by area\Line " + layerName)
                    arcpy.AddMessage("\n Completed split for " + layerName)



arcpy.AddMessage("\n Script complete")
                    #delete variables created
del lyr
del df
del mxd
            #script ends
```

I am currently receiving an error code of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Richard.Lauberts\Documents\LIS Data\Toolbox and Scripts\Python Script for Splitting MasterMap by Site.py", line 26, in <module>
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('OSMM_Line_Detail',"WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",layerName,'110 Meters',"NEW_SELECTION")
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6618, in SelectLayerByLocation
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).
```

I have exported the files to a geodatabase and re-sourced the layers, I have tried to use arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management as suggested in some other posts, tried to hardcode the file names instead of using GetParameterAsTest and nothing seems to help!

For the input for the distance value in the code, I have tried "110", "110 Meters", "110 Metres" and have left it as a getparameters (set to a linear value in the arc toolbox interface allowing user to pick length and unit).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couple of typos ahead:  misplaced "" in 2nd-to-last line.  You might want an "r" front of "C:\Users\etc." to make python read the \ characters literally.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem, but sometimes arcpy's little brain can't quite handle nested commands.  Try taking the GetParameterAsText out of the argument -- make it a separate line with a variable name and change it from text to a numeric format if you need to.